# The buttons of MDList gets stuck after changing to Screen contaning MDDataTable --kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So here is the problem.. Once i changed to Datasheet screen the buttons of MDList gets struck .. Is their any way to fix this

I can't use any other widget other than MDDATATable and i think it is the main problem..
is this a inbuilt bug or is their something wrong in my code.. please clear

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

kv  = '''

<Somecls>:
    scrn_manager : scrn_manager
    MDList:
        size_hint : 0.3,1
        pos_hint : {'x':0.0, 'top':1}
        
        TwoLineListItem:
            text : 'First Screen'
            secondary_text : 'Go to home screen'
            on_release:
                scrn_manager.current = 'Home page'
        TwoLineListItem:
            text : 'Data Sheet'
            secondary_text : 'View Data'
            on_release:
                scrn_manager.current = 'Data Table'

    ScreenManager:
        id : scrn_manager
        size_hint : 0.7,1
        pos_hint : {'x':0.3 , 'top':1}
        
        Screen:
            name : 'Home page'
            Label:
                size_hint : 1,1
                text : 'This is just an example'
        
        Screen:
            name : 'Data Table'
            
            
'''
class Somecls(FloatLayout):
    row_data = ListProperty([])
    column_data = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Somecls, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data_table = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint = {'x':0.01 , 'top':0.96},
            size_hint = (0.8 , 0.96),
            use_pagination = True,
            column_data = [
               ("No.", dp(30)),
               ("Column 1", dp(30)),
               ("Column 2", dp(30)),
               ("Column 3", dp(30)),
               ("Column 4", dp(30)),
               ("Column 5", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data = [
                (
                    f"{i + 1}",
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4",
                    "5",
                )
                for i in range(49)
            ])
        self.scrn_manager.get_screen('Data Table').add_widget(self.data_table)

class Example(MDApp):

    column_data = ListProperty([])
    row_data = ListProperty([])

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Somecls()

Example().run()
```

Any help is apperciated

Answer (score 0):

That is the way `MDDataTable` is designed. It is an extension the kivy `ModalView`, which means that while it is displayed nothing else is operational. I guess the intent is that you must interact with the `MDDataTable` before continuing.

Comment: Bro can u please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `MDDataTable`. Here is a modified version of your code that uses a `RecycleGridLayout` inside a `RecycleView`:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv  = '''
<Somecls>:
    scrn_manager : scrn_manager
    MDList:
        size_hint : 0.3,1
        pos_hint : {'x':0.0, 'top':1}
        
        TwoLineListItem:
            text : 'First Screen'
            secondary_text : 'Go to home screen'
            on_release:
                scrn_manager.current = 'Home page'
        TwoLineListItem:
            text : 'Data Sheet'
            secondary_text : 'View Data'
            on_release:
                scrn_manager.current = 'Data Table'

    ScreenManager:
        id : scrn_manager
        size_hint : 0.7,1
        pos_hint : {'x':0.3 , 'top':1}
        
        Screen:
            name : 'Home page'
            Label:
                size_hint : 1,1
                text : 'This is just an example'
        
        Screen:
            name : 'Data Table'
            RecycleView:
                id: rv
                viewclass: 'MDLabel'
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    row_default_height: 40
                    col_default_width: 200
                    cols: 6
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.minimum_size
'''


class Somecls(FloatLayout):
    row_data = ListProperty([])
    column_data = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Somecls, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup_data_table)

    def setup_data_table(self, dt):
        data = []
        column_data = [
                          ("No.", dp(30)),
                          ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                          ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                          ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                          ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                          ("Column 5", dp(30)),
                      ]
        for col in column_data:
            data.append({'text':col[0], 'size_hint_y':None, 'height':col[1], 'halign':'center'})
        row_data = [
            (
                f"{i + 1}",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
            )
            for i in range(49)
        ]
        for row in row_data:
            for col in row:
                data.append({'text':col, 'halign':'center'})

        self.ids.rv.data = data


class Example(MDApp):

    column_data = ListProperty([])
    row_data = ListProperty([])

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Somecls()

Example().run()
```

Comment: Have a problem bro. If i would have to add a large number of data in the gridlayout than my app will get freeze. That's what happened before with me. So i think i have to use A recycle widget . can u suggest how to implement a recycleview in this code .

Answer (score 0):

It seems i have found a way. Please suggest if it is a great idea.

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList , TwoLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

kv = '''

<Somecls>:
    scrn_manager : scrn_manager
    
    ScreenManager:
        id : scrn_manager
        size_hint : 1,1
        pos_hint : {'x':0.0 , 'top':1}

        Screen:
            name : 'Home page'
            
            MDList:
                size_hint : 0.3,1
                pos_hint : {'x':0.0, 'top':1}
        
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text : 'First Screen'
                    secondary_text : 'Go to home screen'
                    on_release:
                        scrn_manager.current = 'Home page'
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text : 'Data Sheet'
                    secondary_text : 'View Data'
                    on_release:
                        scrn_manager.current = 'Data Table'

            MDLabel:
                size_hint : 1,1
                text : 'Home Page'
                halign : 'center'
                

        Screen:
            name : 'Data Table'

'''

class Somecls(FloatLayout):
    row_data = ListProperty([])
    column_data = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Somecls, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.card_ = MDCard(size_hint = (0.3,1) , pos_hint = {'x':0 , 'top':1} ,elevation = 0)
        self.flt = FloatLayout()

        self.data_table = MDDataTable(
            pos_hint={'x': 0.31, 'top': 0.96},
            size_hint=(0.7, 0.96),
            use_pagination=True,
            rows_num = 10,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Column 1", dp(30)),
                ("Column 2", dp(30)),
                ("Column 3", dp(30)),
                ("Column 4", dp(30)),
                ("Column 5", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (
                    f"{i + 1}",
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4",
                    "5",
                )
                for i in range(49)
            ])

        self.screen_list = MDList(size_hint = (1,1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.0 , 'top':1} )

        self.list_item_1 = TwoLineListItem(text = 'Home Page' , secondary_text = 'Go to home page')
        self.screen_list.add_widget(self.list_item_1)
        self.list_item_1.bind(on_release = self.func1)

        self.list_item_2 = TwoLineListItem(text = 'Data Sheet' , secondary_text = 'Go to datasheet view')
        self.screen_list.add_widget(self.list_item_2)
        self.list_item_2.bind(on_release = self.func2)

        self.scrn_manager.get_screen('Data Table').add_widget(self.data_table)
        self.scrn_manager.get_screen('Data Table').add_widget(self.card_)

        self.flt.add_widget(self.screen_list)

        self.card_.add_widget(self.flt)



    def func1(self,instance):
        self.scrn_manager.current = 'Home page'
    def func2(self,instance):
        self.scrn_manager.current = 'Data Table'

class Example(MDApp):
    column_data = ListProperty([])
    row_data = ListProperty([])

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Somecls()


Example().run()
```